# "TypeError: d is undefined" Google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I try to construct a "bot" message, a create also in "css" the Window but I've got this error:

> TypeError: d is undefined

And I don't have the "map" on screen.

```
function getMessageGrandPy(msg) {
  $.ajax({
    data : {messageInput : msg},
    type : 'POST',
    url : '/process',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      data.messages.forEach(function(message) {
        grandPyMessage(message);
      });
      grandPyMapResponse(data.position);
      lastGrandPyMessage();
    },
  });
};

function grandPyMapResponse(position) {
  $('<div class="message loading new"><figure class="avatar"><img src="../static/images/papy.gif" /></figure><span></span></div>').appendTo($('.mCSB_container'));
  updateScrollbar();
  $('.message.loading').remove();
  $('<div class="message new"><figure class="avatar"><img src="../static/images/papy.gif" /></figure>' + '<div class="mapShow"></div>' + '</div>').appendTo($('.mCSB_container')).addClass('new');
  initMap(position);
  setDate();
  updateScrollbar();
};

function initMap(position) {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementsByClassName('mapShow'),{
    center: position,
    zoom: 19,
  });
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: position,
    map: map,
  });
};
```

Comment: If you remove `setDate();`, `updateScrollbar();` and `marker = new google.maps.Marker({ /* */ })` do you still get the error? Does the map render successfully, disregarding markers or other elements?

Comment: If i try to put : map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map") and change class by id=map ir runs fine but once.

Comment: i change also the HTml code and css to

Comment: I'm not understanding. Are you saying if you remove the other lines and function calls, it still has an error?

Comment: The app runs here:" https://appgrandpy.herokuapp.com/" it's in french, but if you try tu imput for times the map only appear once!

Comment: because a use a ID ... if a try : map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElemenstByCassName("map") and change the HTML.. it never show the map

Comment: Okay so first step sounds like to query and pass a single (1) element to the `google.maps.Map` constructor. `getElementsByClassName` will not return a single element and that will cause issues.

Comment: if i delete the othor fonctions, nothing changes, is just map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElemenstByCassName("map")

Comment: You need to pass a single HTML element to `new google.maps.Map`. Either select a single element when using `getElementsByClassName` or `getElementById`. If you do not have an id on the map element, add one and query it. You can pass the results of getElementsByClassName directly to the map constructor.

Comment: What should i do so i can get the 'map' every time i need?
how can i build the answer then?

Comment: thanks ii will try to auto increment the id and the vars map and

Answer (score 0):

I get that error in firefox if I call `initMap` like this with a valid position:

```
<div class="mapShow"></div>

var map;
var position;

function initMap(position) {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementsByClassName('mapShow'), {
    center: position,
    zoom: 19,
  });
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: position,
    map: map,
  });
}
```

`.getElementsByClassName('mapShow')` returns an array.  To access the first entry, use `document.getElementsByClassName('mapShow')[0]`

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/7ugfcdxw/5/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;
var position;

function initMap(position) {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementsByClassName('mapShow')[0], {
    center: position,
    zoom: 19,
  });
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: position,
    map: map,
  });
  position = map.getCenter();
}

setInterval(function() {
  if (!position)
    position = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
  initMap(position);
  position = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(position, 100, 45);
}, 5000);
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */

.mapShow {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="mapShow"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&libraries=geometry"></script>
```